# JavaScript Security Risks In Hybrid Mobile App

Tags: javascript, security, hybrid-mobile-app

Let's assume HTML5 web page with (in)appropriate server-side background so that http://www.my-site.com/execute?query="SELECT * FROM Table" gets executed via AJAX and returns results. Not very smart, indeed.

But how about when in context of hybrid mobile app, i.e. HTML5 app inside iOS/Android/WindowsPhone wrapper/skeleton delivered as an application through appropriate store?

Q: Do we consider JavaScript safe when in context of hybrid mobile app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say no.

If somebody looks at your network communication, or maybe if you accidently forget some debug logging, it's probably fairly easy to find out the url.
And the query probably would also work when called in a browser (being mobile or desktop).

Of course you can ask yourself: how popular is your mobile app and would anybody even try to hack it. But I wouldn't bet on that.

Edit: we usually use something like a (REST) API, and the answer from the server is JSON which is then parsed by the client. Don't let anybody be able to type in SQL queries!

A: In terms of "security" on iOS: you can browse the device with e.g. iExplorer. On Android, there are also ways (rooted device or adb). Given the phonegap structure, your javascript would then be located in the "assets_www" folder or similar. So if somebody wants to, he/she can look at the javascript source just like on the web.

Comment: OK, good answer, thanks. Now imagine a different example, where there is your username and password to database stored in JavaScript code in the page. On desktop, you would just see the source of the page and you could read it --> not safe. Again - when in context of hybrid mobile app - safe or not?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to put your database login data plaintext into a javascript file?
I wouldn't put that kind of data in javascript, be it mobile or desktop.
Do that server-sided.
Server: connect to DB, request data, deliver data to client
Client: parse data

Comment: There is no server when building mobile app (using PhoneGap/Cordova to target iPad).

Comment: I see. So in terms of "database", you're talking about a local db, probably SQL Lite?
In terms of "security" on iOS: you can browse the device with e.g. iExplorer.
On Android, there are also ways (rooted device or adb). Given the phonegap structure, your javascript would then be located in the "assets_www" folder or similar. So if somebody wants to, he/she can look at the javascript source just like on the web. Don't know if that answers your question now. Haven't used SQL Lite yet.

Comment: this answer is huge and deserves a lot of vote-up.  the battle rages on for hybrid vs native and this is a show stopper for health and life sciences apps.

Answer (score -1):

It will cause a serious misery.
Once someone finds your AJAX url, they will be able to delete or insert anything into your database.

Reverse engineering of applications is very common, so one will be able to find your AJAX URL very easily once they just decompiled your app. Hybrid mobile apps can be very vulnerable if you think of them like native apps.

Additionally, using proguard will not help securing your html/js source codes, so you'd better just think of them as websites' front-end where all the sources are open, and keep the same level of security.